# How to calculate the attendance

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the total attendance for each student. I have two separate tables and I keep the name and ID of the students on student table and keep the attendance and ID on attendance table. On attendace table I have 30 rows for each students and 1 and 0. I would like to list how many attendance (total of 0s)each student has with the name listed. What should be the sql like? Thank you for your help

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN attendance ON students.KategoriID = attendance .KategoriID where WHERE attendance =0 "; 
$sonuc = mysql_query ($sql) ; 
while($satir=mysql_fetch_array($sonuc)) {
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide the table structure and the query that you tried so far?

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN attendance ON students.KategoriID = attendance .KategoriID where WHERE attendance =0 "; 

$sonuc = mysql_query ($sql) ;
    while($satir=mysql_fetch_array($sonuc))
 {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT student.*, count(attendance.attendance) AS absent FROM student 
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.KategoriID =attendance.KategoriID  
AND attendance.attendance=0 GROUP BY attendance.KategoriID ORDER BY    
student.KategoriID;
```

Try this query.

Check the [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b202c/1)